# Is it possible to have a claims authorization with an OR condition like roles?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-3.0

I've always used role authorization in my .net application.  However, I'm building a demo app and want to give claims a try.  I've always decorated my controller like this where either an admin or User with full access can be authorized.

```
[[Authorize(Roles = "IsApiUserFullAccess", "IsAdmin") ]]
```

However, I can't accomplish the same with claims.  In my startup, I have these two claims policies. How can I decorate my controller or change these policies to make either claims to be authorize by my controller?

```
options.AddPolicy("IsApiUserFullAccess", policy => policy.RequireClaim("apiuser.fullaccess", "true"));
options.AddPolicy("IsAdmin", policy => policy.RequireClaim("administrator", "true"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to build a custom policy with a requirement and handler that ORs the user's claims, like so:

```
// Marker class
public class HasFullAccessOrAdminRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement {}

public class HasFullAccessOrAdminHandler 
: AuthorizationHandler<HasFullAccessOrAdminRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, 
        HasFullAccessOrAdminRequirement requirement)
    {
        var user = context.User;
        if (user.HasClaim(...) || user.HasClaim(...))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Then register it:

```
options.AddPolicy("AdminOrFullAccess", builder => 
    builder.AddRequirements(new HasFullAccessOrAdminRequirement());
```

Then use it: `[Authorize("AdminOrFullAccess")]`

Answer (score 10):

You can use the RequireAssertion() method which accepts a Func<> to fullfill a policy.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1#using-a-func-to-fulfill-a-policy)

Example:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AdminOrFullAccess", policy =>
        policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
            {
                bool isApiUserFullAccess = context.User.HasClaim(c => ...);
                bool isAdmin = context.User.IsInRole("ADMIN_ROLE");
                return isAdmin || isApiUserFullAccess;
             });                    
});
```